# SQL JOIN query in elastic search

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, join

I have an elastic search index *COMPANY* which contains documents as below:

```
{
"name": "apple",
"company_id": 1,
"founder": "jobs"
},
{
"name": "google",
"company_id": 2,
"founder": "larry"
}
```

And another elastic search index *PRODUCT* containing documents as below:

```
{
"product": "IPHONE13",
"company_id": "1",
},
{
"product": "IPHONE12",
"company_id": "1",
},
{
"product": "PIXEL 5",
"company_id": "2",
},
{
"product": "PIXEL6",
"company_id": "2",
},
```

Now I want to query these two indices to get output like below but not sure how to do it. I tried querying each index separately and joined their outputs to get the desired result but that did not look like right approach.

```
{
"product": "IPHONE13",
"name": "apple",
"company_id": 1,
"founder": "jobs"
},
{
"product": "IPHONE12",
"name": "apple",
"company_id": 1,
"founder": "jobs"
},
{
"product": "PIXEL5",
"name": "google",
"company_id": 2,
"founder": "larry"
},
{
"product": "PIXEL6",
"name": "google",
"company_id": 2,
"founder": "larry"
}
```

If it is SQL I would have used query:
`select product, name, COMPANY.company_id, founder from COMPANY LEFT JOIN PRODUCT on PRODUCT.company_id=COMPANY.company_id`

But not sure how to do this in Elastic Search. I only have read-access to Elastic Search and cannot denormalize or modify the indexes. Could you please how can we achieve this result using ES queries?

Answer (score 0):

Performing full SQL-style joins in a distributed system like Elasticsearch is prohibitively expensive. instead, Elasticsearch offers two forms of join which are designed to scale horizontally.

you can check [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html) from elasticsearch.